# time series analysis with statsmodels - irregular time interval

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, predict

I am analyzing financial data time series with statsmodels, specifically arima. I want to make a prediction, but I am not sure how to deal with the irregular time intervals. I am getting the error ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1.

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: I can't think of anything that would cause this in the ARIMA code. Can you post code to replicate? If you want to use irregular time-series with ARIMA, you'll probably want to use plain numpy arrays.

Comment: I used numbers instead of datetime objects, and it solved the problem.